# Distinguishing shapefiles from geodatabase feature class with arcpy.Describe() method?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I have a list of layers (`.ListLayers()`) taken from a dataframe 
. In my case the layers can have two types of data source either shapefile or GDB. I want to start different actions depending on the source type. What I thought of so far: it would be possible to compare the 'desc.name[-4:]' with '".shp"' like:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)

for lyr in lyrlist:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)

    if (desc.name[-4:] == ".shp"):
        #do something with the shapefile
    else:
        #do something with the GDB feature class)
```

I still believe this option must be hidden somewhere in the describe method.

**Is it possible to distinguish shapefiles from geodatabase feature class with the arcpy describe() method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Describe object's `dataType` property will return `Shapefile` for a shapefile, and `FeatureClass` for a Geodatabase Feature Class

```
if desc.featureClass.dataType == 'Shapefile':
    #do something to shapefiles

if desc.featureClass.dataType == 'FeatureClass':
    #do something to feature classes
```

From ArcGIS Desktop Help pages for `Describe`

> A Shapefile returns a dataType of "ShapeFile".
>   [Describe - Shapefile](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/shapefile-featureclass-properties.htm)

> A Geodatabase Feature Class returns a dataType of "FeatureClass".
>   [Describe - GDB Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/gdb-featureclass-properties.htm)

Comment: @EikeMike that one had a 'gotcha' of needing the `featureClass` object included.  At first I said to use `desc.dataType` however that doesn't work from within ArcMap looking at a layer (it just returns `featureLayer`)

Answer (score 1):

If you see Describe as just one way to do this, then an alternative is the `dataSource` property of the layer:

```
for lyr in lyrlist:
    if lyr.dataSource[-4:] == ".shp":
        #do something with the shapefile
    else:
        #do something with the GDB feature class)
```